# Как освободить ресурсы во время роботы rxjs interval

Tags: angular, rxjs

У я меня есть рабочий CountDown таймер, который ведет обратный отсчет до определенной даты.

```js
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.interv.unsubscribe();
}

getDays(t) {
    return Math.floor( t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) );
}

getHours(t) {
    return Math.floor( (t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24 );
}

getMinutes(t) {
    return Math.floor( (t / 1000 / 60) % 60 );
}

getSeconds(t) {
    return Math.floor( (t / 1000) % 60 );
}

addZeros(n, needLength = null) {
    needLength = needLength || 2;
    n = String(n);
    while (n.length < needLength) {
      n = "0" + n;
    }
    return n
  }

decriseTime(time) {
        this._trialEndsAt = time;
         this.interv = interval(1000).pipe(
            map((x) => {this._diff = Date.parse(this._trialEndsAt) - Date.parse(new Date().toString());
              })).subscribe((x) => {
                  this._days = this.getDays(this._diff);
                  this._hours = this.getHours(this._diff);
                  this._minutes = this.getMinutes(this._diff);
                  this._seconds = this.getSeconds(this._diff);

                  this.days = this.addZeros(this._days);
                  this.hours = this.addZeros(this._hours);
                  this.minutes = this.addZeros(this._minutes);
                  this.seconds = this.addZeros(this._seconds);
                
              });

        return '<span>' + this.days + '<span>дней</span></span>:<span>' + this.hours + '<span>часов</span></span>:<span>' + this.minutes + '<span>минут</span></span>:<span>' + this.seconds + '<span>секунд</span></span>';
    }
```

```html
<div class="decriseTimer" [innerHTML]="decriseTime(slide.dateCountDown)"></div>
```

Но как только я запускаю страницу, приложение стремительно начинает накапливать данные, и со временем виснет комп. Как здесь правильно освободить ресурсы, чтобы выделенная память не уходила в гигабайты?

Comment: Не совсем понял а зачем здесь дублирование переменных? Это вы так getter/setter реализовали? Как вариант изменить обнаружение изменений на onPush либо вынести interval за пределы angular с помощью ngZone.runOutsideAngular()

Comment: Это для добавления нулей в числя типа 9, чтобы было 09.